# Is there a notion of approximate entanglement breaking (EB) channels?

Tags: quantum-operation, channel-capacity, entanglement-breaking-channels

Is there a notion of approximate entanglement breaking (EB) channels? Say, e.g. the output is always close to a separable state. If so, do the nice properties of the EB channels, such as additive classical capacity, carry over to the approximate case? (On a related note, approximate degradability has been studied in the literature.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This work (https://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.97.012332) may be relevant to your question. The authors have shown that "approximate additivity" holds for "approximately entanglement-breaking channels."

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/13805)